# My sql is not starting a port on XAAMP and I am sending you log file also, PL help whats the error in it?

Tags: mysql

```
2019-08-17 21:29:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-08-17 21:29:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-08-17 21:29:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-08-17 21:29:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-08-17 21:29:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-08-17 21:29:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-08-17 21:29:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=1791378
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1791387; transaction id 163
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-08-17 21:29:47 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-08-17 21:31:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-08-17 21:31:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-08-17 21:31:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-08-17 21:31:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-08-17 21:31:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-08-17 21:31:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-08-17 21:31:26 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1791396; transaction id 163
2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-08-17 21:31:27 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1791405; transaction id 163
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2019-08-17 21:45:02 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: The error is clearly stated in the logfile you included (3 times).

Comment: what is that error and how to resolve it?

Comment: You cannot have 2 processes listening to the same port.

Comment: "Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted."

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: Use a different port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the port of XAMPP to 3307 and left the MySQL untouched. Here's how I did that: *Take into consideration that the line numbers may be different on your system.

In the XAMPP GUI click on "Config" -> "Service and Port Settings" -> "MySQL" tab -> Change Main Port to 3307 -> Save -> Save

Locate the installation file for XAMPP -> open MySQL folder -> open bin folder -> right click on "my.ini" and edit it

Change the following lines: (Line 20) Port = 3306 -> Port = 3307 (Line 28) Port = 3306 -> Port = 3307

Save the file, restart your computer, and the server should run.